# How to write a function with a list as parameters

Tags: python

Here is the question, I'm  trying to deﬁne a function `sample_mean` that takes in a list of numbers as a parameter and returns the sample mean of the the numbers in that list. Here is what I have so far, but I'm not sure it is totally right.

```
def sample_mean(list):
    """ (list) -> number
     takes in a list of numbers as a parameter and returns the sample mean of the the numbers in that list
     sample_mean =
     sample_mean =
    """

    mean = 0
    values = [list]
    for list in values:
        print('The sample mean of', values, 'is', mean(list))
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as an argument to define your *list*. It shadows the built-in [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: If your method takes a list, then `values = [list]` doesn't make sense. The argument you are passing to your list should already be a list, so what you are doing there is not needed. E.g: if you have a list being passed to your method as `[1, 2]`,  then `values = [list]` will turn that to `[[1, 2]]`. Which is definitely what you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `list` as a name because it shadows/hides the builtin [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) class for the scope in which it is declared. Use a name that describes the values in the list, in this case `samples` might be a good name. The function could be implemented with something like this:

```
def sample_mean(samples):
    total = 0
    for value in samples:
        total = total + value
    return total / float(len(samples))
```

Or a shorter version which avoids writing your own loop by making use of Python's `sum()` function :

```
def sample_mean(samples):
    return sum(samples) / float(len(samples))
```

Call the function like this:

```
>>> print(sample_mean([1,2,3,4,5]))
3.0
```

Note the use of `float()` to ensure that the division operation does not lose the fractional part. This is only an issue in Python 2 which uses integer division by default. Alternatively you could add this to the top of your script:

```
from __future__ import division
```

If you are sure that you only need to support Python 3 you can remove the `float()` and ignore the above.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful information. I am all new to coding and python.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above by @idjaw, don't use `list` as a parameter instead use `listr` (for example). Your `values = [list]` is erroneous (also stated by @idjaw) and should be removed.

Also, according to [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), you should not use `"(list) -> number"` in your docstrings as that should only be used for builtins.

Finally, your loop should look like `for l in listr:` and then you add values to your mean variable. divide it by the number of values in the list and print the result.

Comment: I have a question regarding the answer to print a statement like this       "The sample mean of [samples] is [sample_mean]"                   I have this but it wont print the statement like I want it to, samples = 0, for num in samples: print('The sample mean of' , samples, 'is', sample_mean) can someone explain what is wrong?

Comment: is `sample_mean` an `int`? then why would you have `for num in samples:`?

Comment: then remove the for loop.